# Updating an HTML combo box from MySQL DB using PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms

need some help here. It's a very simple web app i'm developing but just needed some help with something.

Here's what's setup. I have a html form with one combo box. All I need is to update this combo box with the entries from a mysql table named 'supplier'. The input to this table 'supplier' is via another form on my website which i've already setup. I need help in auto updating this combo box from the table 'supplier'. Please let me know the php code for it. I've included my code as well. Thanks in advance! I have included the html form as well.

[image: Here's what's happening after making the edits you guys suggested :)]

Comment: did u get anything wrong with this code? place <select> tag before while loop

Comment: Tip: change your database connect to this: `$con = mysql_connect("localhost","user","pass") or die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error()); mysql_select_db("rtgs", $con) or die('Could not select database');`  
Then put this code in a seperate file (connect.php) and include this  at the top of every page you need to connect to your database from with `include('connect.php');`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

replace your code

```
 $result = mysql_query("SELECT supplier FROM supplier"); 
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
                    { 
                    /*echo '<form action="">';*/ 
                    echo "<select name='supplier'>"; 
            echo "<option value = '$row[supplier]'>""</option>"; 
                    echo "</select>";
```

with

```
 $result = mysql_query("SELECT supplier FROM supplier"); 
 echo "<select name='supplier'>"; 
 while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) 
 { 
    echo "<option value = '".$row[supplier]."'>".$row[supplier]."</option>"; 
 }
 echo "</select>";
```

Comment: I never understood why we use the following code :
    echo "<option value = '".$row[supplier]."'>".$row[supplier]."  </option>";

I understood the first part, ie echo "<option value = '".$row[supplier]."'>"</option>. But why do we include the extra .$row[supplier].

Comment: @vjrngn, the extra $row[supplier] for text into SELECT box which display to user. If you don't wrote second, then SELECT box appear blank

Comment: in place of the combo box on my page, this is what is get : 
 "; while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) { echo ""; } echo ""; ?>

Comment: i have edited my original post and added the output that i got after editing the code. check it out

Comment: here is the code you sent me. i just updated it .. but still no luck :

    <?php
      $result = mysql_query("SELECT supplier FROM supplier"); 
      echo "<select name='supplier'>"; 
      while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) 
      { 
      echo "<option value = '".$row[supplier]."'>".$row[supplier]."</option>"; 
      }
      echo "</select>"; 
     ?>

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33345/discussion-between-vjrngn-and-hitesh-siddhapura)

Comment: @vjrngn, create one page(at pastebin.com) of whole page and give me URL.

Answer (score 0):

So,

what is the problem? Is your script not working or do you want a active Combobox on one screen to be updated, when on another screen a new entry for supplier is entered?

Ok, some hints:

1. The "select"-Tag should be placed outside the loop.
2. Put the column name in "
3. Add a display-Value for the options

So, without checking it:

```
/*echo '<form action="">';*/
echo "<select name='supplier'>";    
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
{ 
    echo "<option value = '".$row["supplier"]."'>".$row["supplier"]."</option>"; 
}                        
echo "</select>";
```

Comment: I just want an active combo box to be updated when on another screen a new entry for supplier is entered. :)

Comment: Really? That will be weird AJAX-Stuff!

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here:

```
            $result = mysql_query("SELECT supplier FROM supplier"); 
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
                    { 
                    /*echo '<form action="">';*/ 
                    echo "<select name='supplier'>"; 
            echo "<option value = '$row[supplier]'>""</option>"; 
                    echo "</select>";
```

You're creating the drop down box (the `Select`) inside of the mysql data loop. As @Hitesh has explained. You need to create this outside of the loop and only echo out the data results within. For example:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT supplier FROM supplier");
echo "<select name='supplier'>";
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo "<option value=".$row['supplier'].">".$row['supplier']."</option>";
}
echo "</select>";
```

This will output your drop down box, with all your supplier names as the value and the displayed text options.

If you attempted to do the following:

```
            $result = mysql_query("SELECT supplier FROM supplier"); 
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
                    { 
                    /*echo '<form action="">';*/ 
                    echo "<select name='supplier'>"; 
            echo "<option value = '$row[supplier]'>""</option>"; 
                    echo "</select>"; 
                    }
```

You would just end up with as many drop down boxes as you had suppliers in your database. This is because you're creating a new `Select` box for each record found.

Also, without specifying the second `$row['supplier']` between the `option` tags, you'd just end up with a blank (empty) drop down box.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yeah I got that @LokiSinclair :) thanks.. but im still not getting what i want. I'm posting a screenshot of what's happening.

Answer (score 0):

Here is complete code:

**PHP Code:**

```
<?php
// select box open tag
$selectBoxOpen =  "<select name='supplier'>"; 
// select box close tag
$selectBoxClose =  "</select>";
// select box option tag
$selectBoxOption = ''; 

// connect mysql server
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","user","pass"); 
if (!$con) { 
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error()); 
} 

// select database
mysql_select_db("rtgs", $con); 
// fire mysql query
$result = mysql_query("SELECT supplier FROM supplier");
// play with return result array 
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){   
    $selectBoxOption .="<option value = '".$row['supplier']."'>".$row['supplier']."</option>"; 
}
// create select box tag with mysql result
$selectBox =  $selectBoxOpen.$selectBoxOption.$selectBoxClose;   
?>
```

**HTML Code:**

```
<form action="ntxn.php" method="post">

<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Supplier Name:</td>
        <td> 
            <?php echo $selectBox;?>
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>Bill No. :</td>
        <td><input type ="text" name="billno"/></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>Bill Date : </td>
        <td><input type="date" name="billdate"/></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>Bill Amount : </td>
        <td><input type="text" name="billamt"/></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>NEFT / RTGS No. :</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="rtgs"/></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td><input type="submit" name="Save"/></td>
    </tr>
</table>

</form>
```